# Parsing JSON data in Windows app

Tags: c#, json, windows

Suppose this is my JSON data received through an API:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Test_rom",
        "subtitle": "",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.1.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Jewelry",
        "subtitle": "",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.2.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Jackets",
        "subtitle": "All sizes available",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.3.png"
    }
]
```

I created a class called "RootObject":

```c
public class RootObject {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string subtitle { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

I only want to extract values of "title" keys from the array. How can I achieve that?

I tried the following code, but I am getting error in "Encoding" word:

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
RootObject TotalList = new RootObject();
RootObject childlistonly = new RootObject();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(TotalList.GetType());
TotalList = ser.ReadObject(ms) as RootObject;
string category = "";
foreach(var d in TotalList.title) {
    category = category + " " + d.ToString() + "\n";
}
ResultsText.Text = category;
```

I used the following, but it is giving an error:

```
var titlevariable = myobj.title;
Textblock.Text = titlevariable; // (under a click button method)...
```

Comment: Which language is this? c#?

Comment: yes...  RootObject TotalList = new RootObject(); 
            RootObject childlistonly = new RootObject();  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)); 
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(TotalList.GetType()); 
            TotalList = ser.ReadObject(ms) as RootObject;  string category = "";  foreach(var d in TotalList.title) {category +=  " " + d.ToString() ; }        but i am getting error in "Encoding" word...i have also included JSON.NET library.... please help

Comment: One minor point.... having an array as the wrapper object for JSON is a bit of an antipattern because if the JSON is ever consumed by Javascript, there is an exploit that can be leveraged by changing the Array() type.  The best practice is to have an object at the root level, with the array under one of the keys.

Comment: Could you put your broken code into the question maybe?

Comment: I've added some of your comments to your question, in an attempt to clarify your efforts. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31635038/edit) to add further information and clarification.

Comment: @akg, a couple of things for you to do.  I see you have created an answer to include you code.. this should be in the question.  It's seems your problem is not accessing the data from the json, its loading the json from disk in you RestoreFile . That is a different question...  Why is Instream null?  Are you using a debugger to step through the RestoreFile function? Does the "UserDetails" file exist?  You should delete this question and start another using all the code, and the exact error message.  the question is about successfully deserialising a file.

Comment: @Kickaha ..sorry for uploading question in answer block...I have put a question using little different approach...please see that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach(var d in TotalList) {
    category = category + " " + d.title.ToString() + "\n";
}
```

Comment: i used var titlevariable = myobj.title ...  and then Textblock.Text = titlevariable(under a click button method)...    but this is giving error

Comment: i also tried by this...   var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();     RootObject TotalList = new RootObject();
         RootObject childlistonly = new RootObject();   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
         DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(TotalList.GetType());
         TotalList = ser.ReadObject(ms) as RootObject;
       string category = "";       foreach(var d in TotalList.title)
         { category = category + " " + d.ToString() + "\n"; }
         ResultsText.Text = category;           but failed..  :(

Comment: @akg It looks like you are overthinking it.  also you did not say you tried myObj["Title"] as suggested.  If you provide more code in context maybe someone could help .  Edit your question and provide a class calling your RootObject  method, show what you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried the way suggested by you,but it failed...BTW by another method,i have found solution of this..now i have another problem...i am providing sign in option and after sign in,some data will be shown...now i want that when user opens that app again,he dont have to sign in again and directly can see the data...in other way,,it is call persistent storage in ANDROID...or keeping logged in the user..and thanx for help  :)

Comment: In Button click eventhandler,i am using this... Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
           localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = Textboxname.Text;
           Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];

Comment: how can i use these?? and in which method?

Comment: Post your error, and please put any code in the question not in the comments, it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

@kickaha.. 
 private async void Butoon_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

```
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("http://www.blabla.com/alliance/App/mobilelogin.php?KG=MA&EM="+Textboxname.Text+"&PA="+password.Password);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        RootObject TotalList = new RootObject();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        RootObject resu = (RootObject)ser.ReadObject(ms);
       NavigationContext nav = new NavigationContext()
        {
            ID = resu.USERID.ToString(),
            Name = resu.NAME.ToString(),
            Email = resu.EMAIL.ToString()
      }

        SaveFile();
        RestoreFile(); 
         }
    private async void SaveFile()
    {
        StorageFile userdetailsfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("UserDetails", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        IRandomAccessStream raStream = await userdetailsfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        using (IOutputStream outStream = raStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            // Serialize the Session State.
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(NavigationContext));
            serializer.WriteObject(outStream.AsStreamForWrite(), nav);
            await outStream.FlushAsync();
        }  
    }
    private async void RestoreFile()
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("UserDetails");
       if (file == null) return;
       IRandomAccessStream inStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        // Deserialize the Session State.
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(NavigationContext));
        var StatsDetails = (NavigationContext)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
        inStream.Dispose();   
        string hu = StatsDetails.Name + "\n" + StatsDetails.Email;
        //  UserName.Text = "Welcome " + StatsDetails.Name;
        // UserProfileId = StatsDetails.Id;
        resultblock.Text = hu; 

    }
```

}

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string USERID { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }   
}
public class NavigationContext
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

}

i am getting null value in "instream" property of Restorefile() method...